# How to enable/disable ribbon load balancing depending on http response code?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

Using netflix ribbon sometimes you do not want to load-balance, for example you do not want loadbalancing if response code is 404, but for 503 you do want that.

Now the question is how to configure ribbon to setup rules like I mentioned above?

Comment: From looking at the code and experiment it seems that Ribbon will only retry if the request timed out or returned a `503: Service Unavailable`. For the rest of the errors it will not retry and will return the code back to the client. Not sure if that was your question though...

Comment: We can see that 500 also results in ribbon retrying.

Comment: retrying on the same instance or a different instance of the load balancer?